# Typo3 session timeout set

Tags: session, typo3

I am writing typo3 v6.1 extbase extension for bus ticket booking. And I am storing items(tickets for different dates) to basket using sessions using this code in controller

```
protected function restoreFromSession() {
      $sessionData = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'basket');
      return unserialize($sessionData);
}

protected function writeToSession($object) {
    $sessionData = serialize($object);
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'basket', $sessionData);
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();
    return $this;
}

protected function cleanUpSession() {
   $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'basket', NULL);
   $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();
   return $this;
}
```

But Here I want retain the items in basket only for 5 mins, if no browser activity. (no user login here.)
So after session timeout, if the user proceed further to checkout, i need to display error message.

So My question is how to clear session after 5 mins of user inactivity.

I tried by setting these values in install tool, but no success.

```
'FE' => array(
'lifetime' => '60',
'sessionDataLifetime' => '60',
),
```

But no session clear after 1min of browser inactivity.

Any help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably as you are storing session data without user login you will need to add timeout handling yourself, fortunately it can be done easy with some little mods:

```php
protected function restoreFromSession() {
    $sessionData = unserialize($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'basket'));

    // if current session is to old invalidate it and return null
    if (mktime() >= $this->getSessionTimeout()) {
        $this->cleanUpSession();
        return null;
    }
    // else set new timeout and return the data...
    $this->setSessionTimeout();
    return $sessionData;
}


protected function writeToSession($object) {
    $sessionData = serialize($object);
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'basket', $sessionData);
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();
    $this->setSessionTimeout();
    return $this;
}

protected function cleanUpSession() {
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'basket', NULL);
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'basketLifetime', NULL);
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();
    return $this;
}

protected function setSessionTimeout() {
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'basketLifetime', mktime() + 300);
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();
    return $this;
}

protected function getSessionTimeout() {
    return $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'basketLifetime');
}
```

So you can create for an example a simple a redirect to some action if session is cleared:

```php
if ($this->restoreFromSession() == null) {
    $this->redirect('start');
}
```